# External typing file fails to resolve relative path to its own index.d.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

When building my project with a dependency on react-color, tsc fails to import the dependency with the error:

`node_modules/@types/react-color/lib/components/sketch/Sketch.d.ts(2,41): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../..'.`

The problem goes away if I edit Sketch.d.ts to reference '../../../index.d.ts', so there seems to be some issue with it implicitly identifying the index.d.ts file.

A minimal repro in an otherwise empty ts+react doesn't get a similar issue, so I think there's a problem with my project's config.

### client/tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        //"noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

If you clone [this branch](https://github.com/cynicaloptimist/improved-initiative/tree/react-color) from my repo and run `tsc -p client/` you'll see the error.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I had misconfigured my compilerOptions.module field. Changing it to `commonjs` did the trick.